# Image Convertion in Apache POI

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi

I have the requirement to show image on browser which gets from Word document. I am using Apache POI to extract image but not able to open it in the broswser.I am using below code to save image.

```
 picTable = doc.getPicturesTable();
 List pictures = picTable.getAllPictures();
 if(pictures){
      println("pictures::"+pictures.size())
      Picture pic = (Picture)pictures.get(0);
      file = new File("test.gif")
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)
      out.write(pic.getContent())
      out.close()
 }
```

I have seen below interface method:

In POI api, `PicturesManager interface method savePicture..which

> Stores image (probably on disk). Please, note that different output
>   format support different file types, so image conversion may be
>   required. For example, HTML browsers usually supports PictureType.GIF,
>   PictureType.JPEG, PictureType.PNG, PictureType.TIFF, but rarely
>   PictureType.EMF or PictureType.WMF. FO (Apache FOP) supports at least
>   PNG and SVG types.

Any one have implemented this one or any idea to show up this image in the browser.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Save it as an image in the server and then, serve it.

Comment: You can use something like ImageMagick if you really do need to have the image type converted

Comment: @Alfabravo - as of now i am trying to save the image with the code. But embedded image is visio or some other then it is not opening in browser eventhough i saved it in that way. Only embedded one gif then only it is working.

Comment: Step 1: Have you checked that whatever you're saving is an image? I mean, navigate to the folder and open the image.

Answer (score 0):

I have example for xls document, my code:

```
HSSFPatriarch patriarch = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
if (patriarch != null) {
// Loop through the objects
for (HSSFShape shape : patriarch.getChildren()) {
    if (shape instanceof HSSFPicture) {
        HSSFPicture picture = (HSSFPicture) shape;
        if (picture.getShapeType() == HSSFSimpleShape.OBJECT_TYPE_PICTURE) {
            if (picture.getImageDimension() != null) {

                    HSSFPictureData pictureData = picture.getPictureData();
                    byte[] data = pictureData.getData();
                    String fileName = PATH + picture.getFileName() + "." + pictureData.suggestFileExtension();
                    File file = new File(fileName);
                    try (FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file)) {

                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }

                        fop.write(data);
                        fop.flush();
                        fop.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

In this example PATH is variable to folder on your server, like 'c:/temp/img/' for win or '/www/images/' for nix.

If you need you can check the pictureData.suggestFileExtension() to equals 'png', 'jpg' and etc.

After you run code like this, you can use fileName directly in html page or may be, if you use a proxy, you need to do some additional actions to get link on saved picture.